# Sensitivity of different elements to neutron activation analysis

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrons

When I look at [Ortec AN34 Experiment 17](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ewzech/Application-Note-AN34-Experiments-Nuclear-Science-Experiment-17.pdf), I see that the last page shows relative sensitivity to Neutron activation by weight for different elements. For example, the analysis of Fluorine is shown as being 60x more sensitive than Aluminium.

I am trying to understand where 60x comes from.
Each of those isotopes is 100% abundant.

The thermal neutron capture cross sections for 19F is 9.5 b and 27Al is 232 b.
This gives a x24.4 edge to Al.

The sensitivity is by weight. The atomic masses (Al at 27u atomic mass and F at 19u) will help F by x1.42

1.42/24.4 is far from 60

The ratio of half-lives of the activation product is much shorter for F (11.6s) than Al (139s) ~12. That might be said to help sensitivity?

The [fourth edition of the document](https://www.ortec-online.com/-/media/ametekortec/fourth%20edition%20experiments/fourth-ed-3.pdf?la=en) doesn't contain that table.

Can anyone tell me how to make the numbers agree?

EDIT: Is the discrepancy because the experiment only looks for a single gamma energy and this is a small percentage of the overall gamma spectrum associated with activation?

EDIT: When I look at tables of gamma spectra for these two elements I don't see the gamma energies listed in the table of the first document. Why?

Comment: Are you looking at the total cross section or just the 27Al(n,g)28Al cross section?

Comment: 'Thermal neutron capture cross sections' which I think is the same thing but do correct me if I am wrong.
e.g. https://www.osti.gov/etdeweb/servlets/purl/20332542

Comment: Corroborated by https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Neutron-reaction-cross-section-of-fluorine_fig11_316792136
Actually, when I say corroborated, I have this plot for Fluorine which agrees with the numbers above and from other docs. I find the same numbers in a common document such as https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4335199 pages 217 & 233

Answer (score 2):

Neutron activation of fluorine is 60 times *less*, not *more*, sensitive than aluminium.  You are almost there in your calculation.

The footnote to the "Relative Sensitivity" column in the table states that:

> The numbers in this column indicate the number of units (weight) of an element that provide a count rate equal to the count rate furnished from irradiation of one unit weight of aluminum

This means that we need 60 mg of fluorine to get the same count rate as for 1 mg of aluminium.

Actual sensitivity depends on the experimental details, but as you note we can estimate the ideal sensitivity per unit mass from the capture cross section, atomic mass, and the lifetime.
It also depends on the gamma branching fractions (BF) and detection efficiencies, but the BF are 100% for both fluorine and aluminium and their gamma energies are very similar (1634 and 1779 KeV) so their efficiencies should also be almost identical.
Since this is a counting experiment with background, the [signal-to-noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise#Signal-to-Noise) should be proportional to the square-root of the counting time. This in turn should roughly be the lifetime, so we expect the smallest detectable mass to scale as the inverse square root of the lifetime. (For optimum sensitivity, a sample is irradiated for about its lifetime then counted for about its lifetime, then this is repeated for as many cycles as there is time available.)

Hence we expect the ideal "relative sensitivity" for fluorine to be

$$ \frac{\sigma_n (\mathrm{^{27}\!Al})}{\sigma_n (\mathrm{^{19}F})}\frac{A(\mathrm{^{19}F})}{A(\mathrm{^{27}\!Al})}\sqrt{\frac{\tau(\mathrm{^{27}\!Al})}{\tau(\mathrm{^{19}F})}} = \frac{232\,\mathrm{b}}{9.5\,\mathrm{b}}\frac{19}{27}\sqrt{\frac{139\,\mathrm{s}}{11.6\,\mathrm{s}}}\approx60$$

as reported in the table.

Comment: Doh. Perhaps the column should be titled 'Insensitivity'
Also, thank you very much.